# Does a set having a finite measure imply that the magnitude of the set is finite?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $(\Sigma, F, \mu)$  be a measure space and let $A\in F$.  If  $\mu(A)< \infty$, is it true that $|A|<\infty$ ?

This is a result which seems to make sense intuitively and I would like to use it as a part of a proof I am attempting but cannot seem to be able to prove (or find a counter example to) this lemma.

If it is not true - are there any conditions one could apply to make it true?

Comment: There are so many examples which show that this is not true. For example the Lebesgue measure on any bounded set. In fact the only measure which I think this property would be intuitive is the counting measure.

Comment: You can see that this is a non-starter by considering the interval $A=[0,1]\subset\Bbb R$ with the normal Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note sure I understand the intent. If $\mu$ is any finite measure, then $\mu(A) < \infty$ by definition, even on an uncountably infinite $A$.

E.g. a normal probability measure $p$ would produce $p(\mathbb{R}) = 1$.

Comment: This answers my question, thank you.